# I how to do I keep my Apple Watch's screen on longer?

Tags: apple-watch

Sometimes my Apple Watch's screen dims while I'm still using it. How do I keep the screen on longer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On watchOS 2, you can change the duration the display stays on.

The setting is in the `Settings` icon on the Watch itself and in the `Watch` app on the paired iPhone. Go to `General > Wake Screen` and you can switch between 15 or 70 seconds under the `On Tap` section (you will need to scroll down on the Watch).

Answer (score 2):

Watch OS 2.x allows two options.  (Perhaps in future this can be a single dynamic option with a min-max setting.)

- Go to **Watch App** on **iPhone**
- Tap **General**
- Tap **Wake Screen**
- Select the **ON TAP** Wake setting desired

  - Wake for 15 Seconds
  - Wake for 70 Seconds

    ---

    [image: Watch OS General Settings Wake Screen]